# Preventing a 'select' value change if the chosen option meets a condition - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("select.lec").on('change',function()
        {                       
        var sel = $(this);
        var flag = 0;
        for(i=0;i<lec_course.length;i++)
        {
            if(lec_course[i]==sel.val())
            {
                flag = 1;
                alert('Course '+sel.val()+' has been already specified.');
                //Do something to stop the change
            }
        }
        if(flag!=1)
        {
            reset_sel='';
            var n = lec_course.length;
            lec_course[n] = sel.val();
        }
});
```

In the above code, I need to put in a line of code that would prevent the change of value, and instead just select the option with value='blank'. Any suggestions?

I need a generic solution as there are multiple select elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
   $("select.lec").on('change',function(event)
    {                       
    var sel = $(this);
    var flag = 0;
    for(i=0;i<lec_course.length;i++)
    {
        if(lec_course[i]==sel.val())
        {
           return false;

        }
    }
    if(flag!=1)
    {
        reset_sel='';
        var n = lec_course.length;
        lec_course[n] = sel.val();
    }
});
```

@Rohan Sood  fiddler example =  http://jsfiddle.net/6844R/15/

Comment: Add a little bit of explanation on the new function being used, and why it may work. Throwing code around doesn't quite help future visitors or the OP understand the code.

Comment: @RohanSood could you please provide a fiddler link

Comment: I am in a bit of hurry, have a deadline in the next 20 mins. Fiddle will take too much time.

Comment: I seem to figure out a way to get the value as desired, but unfortunately, I am using a combo-box. The underlying select succesfully changes value, but the input combo-box displays the one chosen by the user.